# Displaying the keyset of a map in a JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to display the keyset of a map in a drop down list and have the value of the selected key selected when the user selects the corresponding key.

```
<form:options items="${alertsPrices}" />
```

The above is my options element (I have to use Spring form rather than a standard html form). At the moment this is passing the value of the selected key rather than the value that the key maps to.

Also, I'm not sure if I need to pass (from the controller) the value of alertsPrices as the entire Map or just the keyset?

The user needs to select a key from the drop down list and this will pass the value that the key maps to rather than the key itself.

Comment: There is no "JSTL form", there are frameworks that have custom tags for forms--it would be useful to tag the question with whatever framework you're using.

Comment: Apologies, it's a spring form, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag):

> The items attribute is typically populated with a collection or array
>   of item objects. itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean
>   properties of those item objects, if specified; otherwise, the item
>   objects themselves will be stringified

So, if you want all the entries of the map in the select box, and want the key of the entry as option label and the value of the entry as the option value, you need to pass the `entrySet()` of the map to the `items` attribute, and use `itemValue="value" itemLabel="key"`.

Comment: I'm not following the bean properties part of the documentation. The map I'm using is defined as a maptype in my items.xml configuration. Do I need to add itemValue and itemLabel attributes to this configuration?

Comment: It's quite simple. The tag expects a collection of beans in the `items` attribute. If you specify `itemValue="foo"`, the tag will call `getFoo()` on the bean to get the value of the option it generates. And if you set `itemLabel="bar"`, it will call `getBar()` on the bean to get the label of the option it generates. In your case, you have a collection of `Map.Entry` instances. And `Map.Entry` has `getKey()` and `getValue()` to access the key and the value of the map entry.

Comment: I've decided to stick with default way Spring does it (using the map key as the value and the map value as the label in the list). Thanks for all the help.